# How to get fieldID of Object from Oobject in C using JNI?

Tags: java, android, c++, java-native-interface

I'm very sorry to come up with this topic again. Since everything developed over the years, old answers might be outdated or something is wrong in my code I couldn't recognize.

I'm new to android developement and usually work with c/c++/python, which is why I want to use the JNI.

I created a regular java native c++ project using Android Studio and tried to access a class that contains a second class (and some intergers, which can be processed without any problems). I changed only the MainAcitvity.java and the native-lib.cpp. The rest was kept original so it's easier for me(us) to debug.

My MainActivity.java code looks like this

```
package com.ultratest;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.TextView;


public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    static {
        System.loadLibrary("native-lib");
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        // Example of a call to a native method
        TextView tv = findViewById(R.id.sample_text);

        zone_plane plane = new zone_plane();
        zone_planes planes = new zone_planes(plane);

        int state = initialize(planes);
        tv.setText(String.valueOf(state));
    }

    public static class zone_plane
    {
    }

    public static class zone_planes
    {
        zone_plane zone_plane;

        zone_planes(zone_plane zone_plane) {
            this.zone_plane = zone_plane;
        }
    }

    public native static int initialize(zone_planes planes);
}
```

while my native-lib.cpp looks like this:

```
#include <jni.h>
#include <string>

extern "C"
JNIEXPORT jint JNICALL
Java_com_ultratest_MainActivity_initialize(JNIEnv *env, jclass clazz, jobject planes) {
    jclass clsPlanes = env->GetObjectClass(planes);
    jfieldID fidZones = env->GetFieldID(clsPlanes, "zone_plane","Lcom/ultratest/MainActivity/zone_plane;");
    return 0;
}
```

However the last line before the retun of the cpp file returns an error and I can't find a way to debug this s***.

The path/signature was generated by Android Studio itself and I can't find a reason, why it should be wrong.

Does anyone here can see anything that crashes the app here?

edit: I've boiled down the code to the minimal to make it easier to investigate.

Comment: That last signature cannot have been generated by Android Studio, as inner classes are denoted with a $ instead of a / (that is for packages)

Comment: I'm sorry, but I guess I should have been more specific. There are two objects: zone_planes and zone_plane. zone_planes have a zone_plane member. 

I can't make it run using $ instead of /.

I also double checked the Android Studio and it always marks everything as false and wants to autocorrect is to: 

jfieldID fidZones = env->GetFieldID(clsPlanes, "zone_plane","Lcom/ultratest/MainActivity/zone_plane;");

Comment: My answer demonstrates what the full (binary) class name is of your `zone_plane` inner class. You're taking the `zone_plane` field, which has that type. I do not know why Android Studio wants to autocorrect it, but either it is wrong or you're not showing everything.

Comment: I tried to reproduce this Android Studio bug, and if you try `env->FindClass("com/ultratest/MainActivity/zone_plane");` it will suggest correcting it to $. Go figure :)

Comment: I've reduced the code so it has no unnecessary stuff.
The first part shows the MainActivity.java and the second part shows the native-lib.cpp

I'm looking for the fieldID so I can access the object via GetObjectField. Is there a better way?

I found an error that might be of interest?

"java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: no type "Lcom/ultratest/MainActivity/zone_plane;" found and so no field "zone_plane" could be found in class "Lcom/ultratest/MainActivity$zone_planes;" or its superclasses"

It basically states what you mentioned before. However, I don't know how to solve it.

Comment: Have you tried actually compiling and testing the version with `$zone_plane`? It really is the right name, and I think you found a bug in the Android Studio linter.

Comment: holy s**. yes, you're right. It is working, when I replace Lcom/ultratest/MainActivity/zone_plane by Lcom/ultratest/MainActivity$zone_plane, while the Android Studio linter marks it as incorrect specifier.

Thank you very much.

Comment: I am guessing the lowercase class name `zone_plane` confuses Android Studio in this case.  Can you rename it to `ZonePlane` instead? In the meantime, filed http://issuetracker.google.com/issues/173554093

Comment: Actually I am mistaken. This has nothing to do with cases of the class name. It's simply a bug in Android Studio. Thanks for bring it up!

Answer (score 1):

I compiled the following minimal java file and inspected the result with `javap -private -s MainActivity`:

```
package com.ultratest;
public class MainActivity {
    public static class zone_plane {}
    private zone_plane zone_plane;
}
```

The result showed the following internal (aka binary) name for `zone_plane`:

```
  private com.ultratest.MainActivity$zone_plane zone_plane;
    descriptor: Lcom/ultratest/MainActivity$zone_plane;
```

As you see, there is a `$` between MainActivity and zone_plane, not a `/`. That denotes an inner class instead of a package hierarchy.

Comment: Moral: don't try to guess JNI signatures. Use the output of `javap -s`. It is never wrong.

Comment: Well, to be fair OP did not guess. That is what android studio suggested they use.